# How does one specify arima (p,d,q) in ugarchspec for ugarchfit in rugarch?

Tags: r, time-series, garch

Basically I'm trying to fit garch(1,1) model with arima order from auto.arima

```
> assign(paste("spec.ret.fin.",colnames(base.name[1]),sep=""),    
+ ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
+ submodel = "GARCH", external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
+ mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2,3,4), include.mean = TRUE, archm = FALSE, 
+ archpow = 1, arfima = FALSE, external.regressors = NULL, archex = FALSE), 
+ distribution.model = "norm", start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list()))
```

This gives the following result:

> spec.ret.fin.chn

```
*---------------------------------*
*       GARCH Model Spec          *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
------------------------------------
GARCH Model     : fGARCH(1,1)
fGARCH Sub-Model    : GARCH
Variance Targeting  : FALSE 

Conditional Mean Dynamics
------------------------------------
Mean Model      : ARFIMA(2,0,3)
Include Mean        : TRUE 
GARCH-in-Mean       : FALSE 

Conditional Distribution
------------------------------------
Distribution    :  norm 
Includes Skew   :  FALSE 
Includes Shape  :  FALSE 
Includes Lambda :  FALSE
```

But the same code with `arfima=TRUE` gives

> spec.ret.fin.chn

```
*---------------------------------*
*       GARCH Model Spec          *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
------------------------------------
GARCH Model     : fGARCH(1,1)
fGARCH Sub-Model    : GARCH
Variance Targeting  : FALSE 

Conditional Mean Dynamics
------------------------------------
Mean Model      : ARFIMA(2,d,3)
Include Mean        : TRUE 
GARCH-in-Mean       : FALSE 

Conditional Distribution
------------------------------------
Distribution    :  norm 
Includes Skew   :  FALSE 
Includes Shape  :  FALSE 
Includes Lambda :  FALSE
```

How does one replace that `d` with the integration order (d) of the arima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have looked at the package [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf), you would have seen that package **rugarch** estimates ARFIMA(p,d,q) model with $0<d<1$. So it is not possible to set the integration order higher than one. If you want to keep the value $d$ fixed set `fixed.pars=list(arfima=d)`. For that naturally you need to set `arfima=TRUE` in the argument `mean.model`.

Comment: @`mpiktas`, suppose i wanted to fit with a mean model of p,d,q 2,3,4 what function do you suggest `rugarch` or `garchFit` or is there others? or do i need to do further differencing until reaching zero `d` before fitting?

Comment: Does your data really conform to d=3? Processes with $d=3$ behave very wildly and usually are not examples of financial data.

Comment: of course not it's only hypothetical, the biggest 'd' in my data are the index of financial sector of greece 'fin.gre' with arima order (1,2,1) while the log return of it 're.fin.gre' is (1,1,3)

Comment: Hm so you have probably monthly data? I suggest looking at other packages then, or apply the ugarch on differenced data.